Oqtane Implementation Documentation for 2sxsc
Could someone point me in the right direction of documentation around implementing 2sxc in Oqtane. I saw that 2sxc is supported in this platform but cannot find anything more.
I'm only seeing DNN documentation on https://2sxc.org/
Thank you!!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is off-topic (documentation request)

2sxc is an installable module/extension for Oqtane. The documentation is entirely made to work Hybrid and things specific to Oqtane or DNN are clearly called out as such.
2sxc and EAV Docs for Oqtane and DNN
I guess maybe I am not understanding what you mean by "implementing 2sxc in Oqtane," - are you asking how to install the module? If not, please explain in more detail what you are asking.
There are a lot of Oqtane related items covered on these checklists (maintained by 2sxc): Azing Oqtane Checklists

Just install it from the Oqtane marketplace - as simple as that ;)
